# C++ stack & heap. Принцип работы при запуске программы

Tags: c++

То что такое `stack` и `heap` объяснять не нужно, материал о том как это работает и что происходит с переменным в функциях больше чем достаточно, но потратив некоторое время заметил, что нету практически адекватных материалов о том, как происходит выделения мэмори при первом запуске программы?
Когда программа компилируется и готовится билд, на тот момент уже высчитывается минимальное нужное количество памяти для ее запуска и работы, а сама программа занимает кусок памяти в `stack`овой области? 
Можно раскрытый ответ или хороший материал, который это описывает?
Как изначально под программу выделяется память и в какой именно части?

Comment: Материалов по этой теме много, но к языку С++ это не имеет никакого отношения. Это вопросы по деталям реализации конкретных сред выполнения, т.е. ОС.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Транслятор знает размеры всех объектов. При входе в функцию выделяется стековый кадр нужного размера и в нем размещаются локальные переменные. Размеры объектов в куче тоже известны или в момент трансляции или в момент исполнения. Аппаратный стек увеличивается по мере работы. Не все функции вызываются при конкретном запуске (ну не прошла программа по этой ветке по воле пользователя), поэтому аппаратный стек от запуска к запуску может быть разным. Вобщем стек в момент запуска не выделен, известна только вершина стека а там уж как пойдет. Иногда и переполнения стека бывают. :-)

Comment: Например, в msvc можно вручную задавать размер кучи и стека через `/HEAP` и `/STACK`. Так что надо читать реализации для разных платформ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Транслятор знает размеры всех объектов. При входе в функцию выделяется стековый кадр нужного размера и в нем размещаются локальные переменные. Размеры объектов в куче тоже известны или в момент трансляции или в момент исполнения. Аппаратный стек увеличивается по мере работы. Не все функции вызываются при конкретном запуске (ну не прошла программа по этой ветке по воле пользователя), поэтому аппаратный стек от запуска к запуску может быть разным. Вобщем стек в момент запуска не выделен, известна только вершина стека а там уж как пойдет. Иногда и переполнения стека (aka stackoverflow) бывают. :-)

UPD1:

А еще бывает **компилированный стек**. Это когда машина без аппаратного стека. Тогда транслятор и линкер анализируют код на предмет какие функции кого вызывают и размещают стек в озу так, чтобы стековые кадры при вызовах не перекрывались. Как-то я пользовался Си-компилятором от фирмы Таскинг (или Кейл, не помню сейчас) для интеловской 51-ой однокристаллки. Эта машина с аппаратным стеком в 5 или 10 байт и он используется только для прерываний. Поэтому для собственно программы там как раз был сделан компилированный стек. И, между прочим, много вызовов помещалось и все работало. Только ругалось на функции обработки прерываний, которые нигде не вызываются. Приходилось им делать вызов, но который в рантайме никогда не срабатывал.

Вот в таких архитектурах стек действительно обсчитывается и выделяется при трансляции и линковке. Но сейчас это не модно, аппаратных ресурсов стало много, так что стек и кучу никто на этапе трансляции не считает.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. 
только спросил это и у мне сегодня сразу на собеседовании задали этот вопрос. как чувствовал.